# How can we transform a nested array inside an object into one concatenated string value separated by commas?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, multidimensional-array

I have the following sample array:

```
mainArray = [
    {id: 15475, name: 'Ali', gender: 'Male', addresses: [
      {address1: 'Lebanon'}, 
      {address2: 'USA'}]
    },
    {id: 15475, name: 'Emily', gender: 'Female', addresses: [
      {address1: 'UK'}, 
      {address2: 'France'}]
    },
];
```

I need to transform it into something like:

```
mainArray = [
    {id: 15475, name: 'Ali', gender: 'Male', addresses: 'Lebanon, USA'},
    {id: 15475, name: 'Emily', gender: 'Female', addresses: 'UK, France }
];
```

In this case, I added all nested arrays inside a an element of the `mainArray` into one single string value.

What I've done so far is, I extracted the key names of the `mainArray`:

```
extractedIndexes = ['id', 'name', 'gender', 'addresses'];
```

And made a loop to check the type of each element inside of the `mainArray`, and if it's an object I will concat the values of the nested array into one single string:

```
for (const idx of this.extractedIndexes) {
  console.log(idx)
  this.mainArray.forEach((elem) => {
    let newItem = '';
    if (typeof (elem[idx]) == 'object') {
      elem[idx] = Object.keys(elem[idx]).forEach((key) => {
        console.log(elem[idx][key])
        // Add it to the field
      })
      console.log(elem[idx])
    }
  })
}
console.log(this.mainArray)
```

This line `console.log(elem[idx][key])` is always returning the following:

```
{address1: "Lebanon"}

{address2: "USA"}

{address1: "UK"}

{address2: "France"}
```

Take note that here `address1` and `address2` are simple examples, as my real data contain multiple nested arrays, and each one have different new key names.

I tried to do the following:

```
if (typeof (elem[idx]) == 'object') {
  elem[idx] = elem[idx].toString().split(',')
  // Add it to the field
  console.log(elem[idx])
}
```

But it returned `[Object, Object]`.

So how can I transform a nested array into single concatenated string value?

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-splitting-nested-array-into-string-3w3gsh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `map` and use `Object.values` to get values from object:

```
mainArray.map(({addresses, ...rest}) => ({...rest, addresses: 
    addresses.map(s => Object.values(s)).join(', ')}) );
```

An example:

```js
let mainArray = [
    {id: 15475, name: 'Ali', gender: 'Male', addresses: [
      {address1: 'Lebanon'},
      {address2: 'USA'}]
    },
    {id: 15475, name: 'Emily', gender: 'Female', addresses: [
      {address1: 'UK'},
      {address2: 'France'}]
    },
];

const result = mainArray.map(({addresses, ...rest}) => ({...rest, addresses: addresses.map(s => Object.values(s)).join(', ')}) );
console.log(result);
```

If you don't know whether the key is array, then you can try to use `reduce` method:

```
const result = mainArray.reduce((a, c)=> {
  for (const key in c) {
      if (Array.isArray(c[key]))
        c[key] = c[key].map(s => Object.values(s)).join(', ');
  }
  a.push(c);
  return a;
},[])
console.log(result);
```

An example:

```js
let mainArray = [
    {id: 15475, name: 'Ali', gender: 'Male', addresses: [
      {address1: 'Lebanon'},
      {address2: 'USA'}]
    },
    {id: 15475, name: 'Emily', gender: 'Female', addresses: [
      {address1: 'UK'},
      {address2: 'France'}]
    },
];

const result = mainArray.reduce((a, c)=> {
  for (const key in c) {
      if (Array.isArray(c[key]))
        c[key] = c[key].map(s => Object.values(s)).join(', ');
  }
  a.push(c);
  return a;
},[])
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It didn't work on a generalized array where I don't know what the key name might be. Here you are assuming that there is only a field `addresses`. I added a function to the same stack blitz, can you check it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursive function to get addresses that will work on any nested structure and get the value if the key starts with `address` and value is not an object.

```js
const data =[{"id":15475,"name":"Ali","gender":"Male","addresses":[{"address1":"Lebanon"},{"address2":"USA"}]},{"id":15475,"name":"Emily","gender":"Female","addresses":[{"address1":"UK"},{"address2":"France"}]}]

const flat = (data, prev = '') => {
  let sep = prev ? ', ' : ''
  let result = '';

  for (let i in data) {
    if (typeof data[i] == 'object') {
      result += flat(data[i], prev + result)
    } else if (i.startsWith('address')) {
      result += sep + data[i]
    }
  }

  return result
}

const result = data.map(({
    addresses,
    ...rest
  }) =>
  ({ ...rest,
    addresses: flat(addresses)
  }))


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

````
    {id: 15475, name: 'Ali', gender: 'Male', addresses: [
      {address1: 'Lebanon'}, 
      {address2: 'USA'}]
    },
    {id: 15475, name: 'Emily', gender: 'Female', addresses: [
      {address1: 'UK'}, 
      {address2: 'France'}]
    },
];<br>

function toString(arro) {
  return arro.reduce(
    (acc, rec) => {
      return [...acc, Object.values(rec)]
    }, []
  ).join(',')
}

const res = mainArray.map(
  it => {
    return Object.keys(it).reduce(
      (acc, item) => {
        if (typeof it[item] === 'object') {
          return {...acc, [item]: toString(it[item])}
        }
        return {...acc, [item]: it[item]}
      }, {}
    )
  }
)```
````